# Rigid Body is rolling/spinning on collision, is there a way to have it slide on surfaces instead?

Tags: unity, collision-detection, rotation, collision-resolution, rigidbody

[image: Demo]

I have a rigid body with a sphere as a collision mesh which can move and rotate freely. It realistically spins when colliding with other objects, but this is annoying from a gameplay standpoint. Is there a way to have the rigid body be slippery or just not rotate as much when colliding with objects?

Comment: Rotate freely means around all axle? Else you could freeze one if you dont want to rotate around that one. Or increase friction of your material

Comment: I think increasing friction would have the opposite effect, making the surface of the sphere more "grippy" so sliding contact rotates it. Can you clarify what *should* rotate the sphere? If it's only player control that should do it, we can lock rotation from physics effects. But if you want some hybrid where collisions rotate a little but not much then you may need something more custom.